# How to change language of android app in Android Kitkat version (API 19)?

Tags: android

This the method I am using to switch to Pashto language. It is working fine for Oreo but it's not working for KitKat. This code updates the layout from LTR to RTL. But updated strings are not loading in the textview.

```
public fun loadLanguage(){
    val locale = Locale("ps", "rAF")
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
    val configuration = Configuration()
    configuration.locale = locale
    baseContext.resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, 
           baseContext.resources.displayMetrics)
    val context = LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, "ps")
    val resources = context.resources
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!. 
The problem was that some phone doesn't support the mentioned language. I put all my string in a file with language which is supported by most of the phones. And it worked.